# Need an analogue of output = input("ask something") in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
import System.IO
fileName = "data.txt"
main = do
  putStr "Enter Point :"
  information <- getLine
  let final = ['\n'] ++ information
  appendFile fileName final
  putStrLn "Done !"
```

Successful compilation but there is a runtime error : Program asks for input first then executes the putStr function.

```
hello
Enter Point :Done !
```

I think there should be an explanation of why Haskell isn't following the sequence (maybe it's because of its functional nature).
Any explanation will be highly appreciated ! ( I am new to functional paradigm )

Comment: Try counter by adding another blank input line after the first input

Answer (score 1):

It is following the sequence, it is simply *buffering* the `Enter Point :" part since the standard buffering policy is to wait until a next line is written to the output channel.

You can flush the standard output channel with:

```
import System.IO

fileName = "data.txt"
main = do
  putStr "Enter Point :"
  hFlush stdout  -- flush the output channel
  information <- getLine
  let final = ['\n'] ++ information
  appendFile fileName final
  putStrLn "Done !"
```